# Check how many times a character occurs consecutively in a String

Tags: java, string, loops

I am trying to count the number of times a character occurred consecutively in a String. Can't seem to go anywhere with this :\
I would be highly appreciative if ye can help me out.

Thanks in advance :)

```
        int totCharacters=0, vowels=0, digits=0, odds=0, consecutive=0, index=0;
        String text;
        char ch;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a sentence terminated with a full stop or exclamation mark: ");
        text = input.nextLine();

        do {
            ch = text.charAt(index);

            if(ch=='.' && ch=='!')
                break;

            if(index<text.length()-1)
                totCharacters++;
            if(ch=='a' || ch=='e' || ch=='i' || ch=='o' || ch=='u')
                vowels++;
            if(ch>='0' && ch<='9')
                digits++;
            if(ch=='1' || ch=='3' || ch=='5' || ch=='7' || ch=='9')
                odds++;

            index++;

        }while(ch!= '.' && ch!='!');

        for(int i=0; i<text.length(); i++)
        {

            if(ch==text.charAt(i))
                consecutive++;

        }
```

Comment: Try a regexp instead?

Comment: Your title says `occurs consecutively` but your description just says `occurred`. Which one is it?

Comment: @CMate not allowed to use regexp :(

Comment: @peeskillet sorry, yeah i should have mentioned consecutively as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will count ALL consecutive chars ( i believe, can't compile atm).  This is probably not what you want. I can modify depending on what you mean by consecutive characters.  ALL consecutive? highest consecutive?

I moved the for loop inside the do while so that you do it to each char. I also base the int i variable off of index so that you don't look at characters before the current one you are examining. Also moved the incrementing of the index to after the for loop so that it counts itself as one consecutive so "AA" would be 2 consecutive.

I need your definition of what consecutive should equal to make this calculate correctly though. Right now it's going to look at each character and add 1 to consecutive for each matching character after itself (includes itself).

```
    int totCharacters=0, vowels=0, digits=0, odds=0, consecutive=0, index=0;
    String text;
    char ch;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a sentence terminated with a full stop or exclamation mark: ");
    text = input.nextLine();

    do {
        ch = text.charAt(index);

        if(ch=='.' && ch=='!')
            break;

        if(index<text.length()-1)
            totCharacters++;
        if(ch=='a' || ch=='e' || ch=='i' || ch=='o' || ch=='u')
            vowels++;
        if(ch>='0' && ch<='9')
            digits++;
        if(ch=='1' || ch=='3' || ch=='5' || ch=='7' || ch=='9')
            odds++;


    for(int i=index; i<text.length(); i++)
        {

             if(ch==text.charAt(i))
             {
                consecutive++;
             }
             else 
             {
                 break;
             }

        }
        index++;
        }while(ch!= '.' && ch!='!');
```

Comment: Sound man!! Works grand for me :) Couldn't be more happier :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Be careful with the way it's written now, it may take something like "AAA" and count it as 6 consecutive (AAA plus AA plus A).  I left out resetting consecutive so that you could adjust to what your needs are.

Comment: Yeah, I just realised that as well. How would I reset it though?

Comment: `index++` should go above the for loop as well :)

Comment: I put index++ beneath the loop so that the current character would be counted as a consecutive (as it should). Are you trying to find the highest consecutive count of any character? what exactly (in detail) are you trying to find with consecutive. "Consecutive characters" could be counted in MANY ways.

Comment: Might be a good idea to take a few minutes and put some example input into your example and what the expected Consecutive Chars count would be in the case of each input. Like, does AAABBBB = 4 consec chars (4 is longest consecutive) or does AAABBBB = 7 (3 consecutive A's and 4 consecutive B's)

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume the problem is that it is not counting `consecutive` the way you expect. The problem is that the `for` loop is running after you've gone through all the characters. Since `ch` is set the last time when a '.' or '!' is encountered, the for loop is just counting all the '.' or '!' characters. And not just the consecutive ones.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this. Have two string, one holding all consonants, the other holding all the vowels. Check if one of the strings contains the character. If not, then it is a punctuation or space. The code filters out the space.

```
String consString = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ";
String vowelString = "aeiouAEIOU";

for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
    if (consString.contains(s.charAt(i)){
        consCount++;
    }
    else if (vowelString.contains(s.charAt(i)){
        vowelCount++;
    } 
    else if (!Character.isWhiteSpace(s.charAt(i))
        punctCount++;
    }
}
```

You can do this for any character set you want. Also if you want to count consecutives, you can keep a currentChar variable and check if the next variable equals it. If it does, `consecutives++`